# Group by hour in IQueryable

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

In my project I receive some data from an SPS all x seconds. Every y minutes I archive the current Data in a database so I'm able to show statistics.

The data I receive gets put in a model. Something like this but much more complex:

```
public class Data
{
    public DateTime ArchiveTime { get; set; }
    public float TempC { get; set; }
    public float CO2Percent { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository for the database that returns all entries in a certain time span. See this code:

```
// Context is my DbContext for a SQLite db and Data is the DbSet<Data> on that
IQueryable<Data> GetDataBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) => Context.Data.Where(d => (d.ArchiveTime >= from && d.ArchiveTime <= to));
```

As you can see this returns an `IQueryable` so I want to make use of the linq to entities functionality.
*I believe it's called linq to entities but in case it isn't, I mean the functionality that converts expression trees to sql or whatever instead of just executing it in C#.*

Since there is an indeterminable amount of entries per hour in the database I want to **only get one entry per hour (the first one)** so I can display it in a graph.

Here's an example of some datetimes that maybe show my intent a bit better:
**NOTE:** these are only the datetimes contained in the object, I want the whole object - not just the times.

```
// say this is all the data I get between two times
2019-07-06 10:30:01 // I want
2019-07-06 10:40:09
2019-07-06 10:50:10
2019-07-06 11:00:13 // I want
2019-07-06 11:10:20
2019-07-06 11:20:22
2019-07-06 11:30:24
2019-07-06 11:40:32
2019-07-06 11:50:33
2019-07-06 12:00:35 // I want
2019-07-06 12:10:43
2019-07-06 12:20:45
2019-07-06 12:40:54
2019-07-06 12:50:56
2019-07-06 13:00:58 // I want
2019-07-06 13:11:06
2019-07-06 13:21:08
2019-07-06 13:31:09
```

The current way I do this is via a `IEnumerable` and `GroupBy`. See this code:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
IQueryable<Data> dataLastWeek = repos.GetDataBetween(now.AddDays(-7), now);

IEnumerable<Data> onePerHour = dataLastWeek.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(d => new DateTime(d.ArchiveTime.Year, d.ArchiveTime.Month, d.ArchiveTime.Day, d.ArchiveTime.Hour, 0, 0))
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

This works fine but since it uses `IEnumerable` and creates objects, I don't get the advantages of linq to entities and I think it must a lot slower this way.

Is there any way to rewrite this query to work with `IQueryable` on a SQLite database?

EDIT: I'm working with the .net core 3 preview6 (newest preview) version of EF Core. Maybe there is a new feature that allowes for what I want :)

Comment: I guess you tried it without the AsEnumerable and it didn't work which could be because the LINQ provider can't really convert `new DateTime(...)` or the `First(...)` of a grouping to SQL. However, I think `dataLastWeek.GroupBy(d => new { d.ArchiveTime.Year, d.ArchiveTime.Month, d.ArchiveTime.Day, d.ArchiveTime.Hour }).Select(g => g.Min(x => x.ArchiveTime));` should work as this can be expressed in SQL as `SELECT MIN(ArchiveTime) FROM data GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, ArchiveTime), DATEPART(MONTH, ArchiveTime), DATEPART(DAY, ArchiveTime), DATEPART(HOUR, ArchiveTime)`.

Comment: Yes I did try that (without the `AsEnumerable`) and you're correct that this didn't work. Also the solution you're suggesting returns only the `DateTime`, not the `Data`-object itself :/

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` is not needed in EF Core. Unfortunately with the current EF Core query translation, the query will use client evaluation anyway because of the `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev if I don't use `AsEnumerable()` it thinks I want to do a `where` on the `IQueryable` which throws an exception since I create a new `DateTime` and how would EF know how to do that. Is there any way to remove the first then? @juharr mentions `OrderBy` but how would you use that in this context? With `Take(1)`?

Comment: @ckuri I edited the question to add a note that I want the full object, not just the datetimes. Your solution seems to work fine but as mentioned, only returns the datetimes.

Comment: Assuming EF Core 2.2, that part can easily be fixed with anonymous type, e.g. `.GroupBy(d => new { d.ArchiveTime.Date, d.ArchiveTime.Hour })`. As I said, the problem is with `First()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I know, @ckuri already provided a working solution for that. Is there no replacement for `First()`? I was thinking you might need to use subqueries but I'm not sure how you would implement that.

Comment: Unfortunately no. `First` definitely should not be used because it forces client eval, but unfortunately all other possible patterns like `OrderBy()` + `Take(1)` or `FirstOrDefault()` also lead to client eval (although not forced).

Comment: @IvanStoev Hmm. There is a [`First` implementation for `IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.first?view=netcore-3.0) but I guess this doesn't mean it won't use client eval :/

Comment: Indeed. And they do it intentionally - see below. Also the best workaround I can think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key part of the `GroupBy` can easily be made translatable by avoiding `new DateTime(...)` and using either anonymous type

```
.GroupBy(d => new { d.ArchiveTime.Date, d.ArchiveTime.Hour })
```

or `Date` property + `AddHours`:

```
.GroupBy(d => d.ArchiveTime.Date.AddHours(d.ArchiveTime.Hour))
```

Unfortunately currently (EF Core 2.2) does not translate nested `First` / `FirstOrDefault` / `Take(1)` to SQL and uses client evaluation. For `First()` it is forced in order to emulate the LINQ to Objects throwing behavior, but for the other two patterns it's caused by the lack of proper translation.

The only server side solution I see for your concrete query is to not use `GroupBy` at all, but correlated self antijoin, something like this:

```
var onePerHour = dataLastWeek.Where(d => !dataLastWeek.Any(d2 =>
    d2.ArchiveTime.Date == d.ArchiveTime.Date &&
    d2.ArchiveTime.Hour == d.ArchiveTime.Hour &&
    d2.ArchiveTime < d.ArchiveTime));
```

Comment: This works, thanks. However you only check for year and hour - any reason for that? To get the behaviour I want (and had with the old solution) you need to also check month and day otherwise you only get 24 entries.

Comment: Very quickly.. I don't directly use the data for the graph but create tupels from it. These are unknown to ef so it throws if I do a `select` on the `IQueryable`. When I use `AsEnumerable` it works but it's very slow. Using `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable` speeds it up by a factor of about 3. So is it correct to call `ToList()` on `onePerHour` before I create my tupels?

Comment: (1) Sorry, copy/paste mistake, I meant `Date` (2) Not sure what you mean, `ToList()` loads everything in memory.

Comment: I have asked [a follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040867/create-custom-objects-from-iqueryable-without-loading-everything-into-memory). I'd appreciate it if you looked into it when you have time :)